# Is there a local wallet for Ripple?

Tags: ripple, ripple-client

The only wallet I can find for Ripple is the standard web client. I don't like the idea of always having to trust a web client with my keys. Is there a local-only client for the Ripple network? If not, is there something preventing a local client from being developed or has it just not got enough interest yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ripple Labs makes a [downloadable client](https://download.ripple.com/) available. You can store wallets in a local file, encrypted with a passphrase. The source code is available on [github](https://github.com/ripple/ripple-client-desktop) along with build instructions.

Comment: Are you familiar with the desktop wallet below? We wouldn't want to be distributing malware.